# "Мама — замечательный человек". Нужно ли тире?

Tags: пунктуация, тире, сказуемые

**Мама — замечательный человек.**
Нужно ли тире в этом предложении? Сказуемое здесь *человек* или *замечательный человек*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну конечно, сказуемое здесь "человек", а "замечательный" - определение. По правилам тире здесь ставится (см. раздел "Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым" в любом справочнике).

В подобных случаях говорят, что слово "человек" *лексически опустошено* (еще пример: "Дружба - *вещь* святая"). Но лексически, а не грамматически.

Comment: Тогда почему в "Капитанской дочке" читаем: Василиса Егоровна прехрабрая дама (тире отсутствует); Маша трусиха (тоже без тире)?

Comment: Потому что Пушкин писал почти 200 лет назад. Потому что это художественное произведение, и автор имеет право на т. наз. "авторскую пунктуацию". Вот Горький любил тире, пихал его всюду, где только можно, а Пушкин, возможно, нет. Интересно было бы поискать у Пушкина подобные фразы и посмотреть, часто ли он ставил тире (правда, надо быть уверенным, что пушкинская пунктуация всюду сохранена).

Comment: Возможно, Вы правы, но я думаю, что это наша современная редакция так расставляет знаки препинания.